# What kind of numerical method does 'pdepe' (MATLAB function's) use?

Tags: matlab, function, numerical-methods, pde

I'm using the MATLAB's function 'pdepe' to solve a problem with some partial differential equations, a parabolic one.

I need to know the kind of numerical method that function uses, 'cause I have to notify this in a report.

The description of the function in MathWorks is "Solve initial-boundary value problems for systems of parabolic and elliptic PDEs in one space variable and time". Is it a finite difference method?

Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from the Matlab 2016b documentation for `pdepe`:

> The time integration is done with ode15s. pdepe exploits the
>   capabilities of ode15s for solving the differential-algebraic
>   equations that arise when Equation 1-3 contains elliptic equations,
>   and for handling Jacobians with a specified sparsity pattern.

Also, from the `ode15s` documentation:

> ode15s is a variable-step, variable-order (VSVO) solver based on the
>   numerical differentiation formulas (NDFs) of orders 1 to 5.
>   Optionally, it can use the backward differentiation formulas (BDFs,
>   also known as Gear's method) that are usually less efficient

Answer (score 2):

As [indicated by Alessandro Trigilio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43174272/3121310), `ode15s` is used to advance the solution forward in time.  Exactly what the function is advancing in time is a semi-discrete, second-order Galerkin formulation for non-singular problems or a semi-discrete, second-order Petrov-Galerkin formulation for singular problems (polar or spherical meshes that include the origin).  As such, the spatial discretization is finite element in nature.